# issue accessing arrays with aws result with php

Tags: php, json

I have got a result back from the AWS API and im trying to pick out data from the returned JSON, i want to be able to read results and use for inserting into a SQL DB

here is my code

```
$result = $ec2Client->describeInstances();
$result2 = json_encode($result->toArray(), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
$info = (json_decode($result2, true));

foreach($info['Reservations'] as $currFeature)
{
    $currEvent = $currFeature['Instances']['ImageId'];
    echo $currEvent;
}
```

but i get the following returned

> Undefined index: ImageId in C:\aws\index.php on line 34

Can someone advise on the how i can reference instance id in the results, here is an extract from the output i want to pull some the data out so can refenrece it, many thanks for your support

```
array(2) {
  ["Reservations"]=>
  array(17) {
    [0]=>
    array(4) {
      ["Groups"]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["Instances"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        array(36) {
          ["AmiLaunchIndex"]=>
          int(0)
          ["ImageId"]=>
          string(AWS result) "ami-00967c66c84d2044e"
          ["InstanceId"]=>
          string(19) "i-0404f283a4dd61304"
```

Thanks

Comment: Hint : `$currFeature['Instances']` is an array of instances.

Comment: HI syscall what would the syntax need to be? just looking for a pointer.  thanks

Comment: :-( still getting errors

Comment: Please, refer to answers in the linked question.